# Transforming Avro to Parquet in Azure

Tags: azure, avro, parquet

I have hundreds of avro files created daily in Azure BLOB account. These avro files contain JSON objects with varying schemas. Each file size ranges between 100KB to 1 MB. I need to transform them into parquet format and store in the same Azure BLOB account.

My constraints: I need to use Azure native services. I do not want to use Azure Functions as even a single file may take a substantial time to transform, which Azure Functions will not handle. Hence, not looking for Azure Functions as the core of the solution.

What would be the most optimal approach, given the requirements/constraints described?

sample input avro:

```
{
    "SequenceNumber": 123, 
    "Offset": "21212", 
    "EnqueuedTimeUtc": "2/18/2022 3:54:39 PM", 
    "SystemProperties": 
        {
            "x-opt-kafka-key": "211223131", 
            "x-opt-enqueued-time": 12321312321
        }, 
    "Properties": 
        {
            "element1": "value1", 
            "element2": "value2"}, 
    "Body":"{ 
                        \"version\":\"1.0\",
                        \"type\":\"some-type\",
                        \"data\":{
                                            \"id\":\"some-id\",
                                            \"color\":\"some-color\"
                                            \"address\":{
                                                                    \"line1\":\"some-line\",
                                                                    \"line-2\":\"some-line\"                                        },
}}
```

P.S. I have done it in AWS with Glue. However, ADF does not handle complex avro files well.

Much help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would be useful.  Just a few records.

Comment: Just a few records would not be enough. If it was that simple, I would not ask this question. Sample data: any complex Avro file containing Map type. Expected result: described avro file converted/flattened to an equivalent parquet file. Not looking for code, but for services in Azure capable of accomplishing it, as described in requirements. NOTE: ADF does not support processing Avro with Map type objects, nor Azure Stream Analytics.

Comment: We do this with Synapse Notebooks and Synapse Pipelines.  It’s Spark doing the heavy lifting.  I can show you some  sample code but I need to understand if it fits your use case.  I don’t need to see all your possible avro, just a sample and your expected results.  Try saying “I have something that looks like this and I want it to end up like this”.

Comment: Azure Data Factory doing the orchestration and Databricks could do the same thing.

Comment: FYI service/tool recommendation questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. I would just take a look at the various data services to see which one suits your preference, budget, etc. (Data Factory, Stream Analytics, Databricks, HDInsight, etc...)

Comment: @David Makogon: I have seen how others have asked similar type of questions and got useful responses. Hence my post. Data Factory and Stream Analytics can't handle avro with map type.

Answer (score 2):

I do a very similar use case to convert avro into flat relational tables using Azure Synapse Analytics.  The key components are as follows:

[image]

- Azure Data Lake Gen 2 - avro files are stored in the data lake
- Synapse Pipelines - pipelines pick up the avro files using Get Metadata activities to get information about the files, For Each activities running in parallel to process each file
- Synapse Notebooks - parameterised Spark notebooks which open the raw avro file and flatten it into a relational form using only a few lines of Scala.  This could easily be adapted to save the files out as parquet.

Azure Data Factory (ADF) and Databricks would offer a similar architecture.

For costs, you would have to try it for your scenario, but the [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator) can give you an idea for starters.  For Synapse Notebooks, it will also depend on the size of the Spark pools you use.  These can be small, medium, large, Xlarge, and XXLarge, with costs rising accordingly.  I would suggest trying both for a smaller number of the files, do a comparison and which one you found easier to work with, faster, cheaper etc

For my example, we have an avro file with two columns, header and body.  We're only interested in the body column which contains json and saving it to a database.  Our json isn't particularly complicated but we do deal with many different amounts of columns.  A simplified example:

### Parameters cell

```
val pSourceFilePath = "abfss://somefilesystem@someStorageAccount.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/somepath/"
```

### Load cell

This deceptively simple `spark.read.load` statement reads our particular file format, but you may need to change to `spark.read.format("avro")` - it really depends on your files:

```
// Read the parquet file and assign to dataframe
val df = spark.read.
    load(s"${pSourceFilePath}")
```

### Expand cell

This again deceptively simple code, using the asterisk syntax (*) to expand all the json to relational columns - this works for our format but I can't be sure it will work for yours:

```
// Expand the json column to many columns
val df2 = df.select($"body.*", input_file_name.as("filename"))
```

You could then write the dataframe, which is now in a more familiar columnar format, to parquet.

Comment: Thank you wBob. Which option would have lower costs? Synapse or ADF/Databricks. I am already doing it in Databricks, but was looking for something with all Azure-native. Also, could you share the code reading and transforming the avro data into the dataframe?

Comment: Any update on this?